# Idiomatic means of Parsing GUI Input Strings for Modular UI Components in Rust

Tags: rust

I'm creating some User Input components in Rust. I'm trying to modularize these components using trait `CustomInput`. This trait implements some basic for all UI Input components, like being able to set and get the values of the component. All my UI components will take a `String` input, and parse that string to some typed value, maybe an `f64`, `i32`, or `Path`. Because different UI components can return different types, I created enum `CustomOutputType`, so that `get_value` can have a single return type for all components.

As users can input any random string, each UI component needs to have a means of ensuring that the input string can be successfully converted to the right type for the respective input component, I.e `MyFloatInput` needs to return a `f64` value, `MyIntInput` needs to return an `i32`, and so on. I see that [`std::str::FromStr`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/str/trait.FromStr.html) is implemented for most basic types, `bool`, `f64`, `usize`, but I don't think this kind of parsing is robust enough for UI inputs.

I'd like some more advanced functionality than `std::str::FromStr` provides, I'd like to be able to:

- Evaluate expression, i.e input of `500/25` returns `20`
- Floor/Ceiling for min/max values: i.e if max is 1000 and input is 2000, value is 1000

1. What would be an idiomatic way of implementing such parsing
   functionality for my UI components?
2. Is using the `CustomOutputType` enum an efficient strategy for handling the
   different types the UI Components could return?
3. Would a parsing crate like [Nom](https://crates.io/crates/nom) be advisable in this situation? I think this might be
   overkill for what I'm doing, but I'm not sure.

[image: UI Inputs]
I've taken a stab at creating such a system:

```rust
use std::str::FromStr;
use snafu::{Snafu};
#[derive(Debug, Snafu)]
pub enum Error{
    #[snafu(display("Incorrect Type: {:?}", msg))]
    IncorrectInputType{msg: String},
}

type Result<T, E = Error> = std::result::Result<T, E>;
#[derive(Clone, Debug)]
pub enum CustomOutputType{
    CFloat(f64),
    CInt(i32),
}

pub trait CustomInput{
    fn get_value(&self)->CustomOutputType;
    fn set_value(&mut self, val: String)->Result<()>;
}
pub struct MyFloatInput{
    val: f64,
}
pub struct MyIntInput{
    val: i32
}

impl CustomInput for MyFloatInput{
    fn get_value(&self)->CustomOutputType{
        CustomOutputType::CFloat(self.val)
    }
    fn set_value(&mut self, val: String)->Result<()>{
        match f64::from_str(&val) {
            Ok(inp)=>Ok(self.val = inp),
            // Ok(inp)=>{self.val = inp}
            Err(e) => IncorrectInputType { msg: "setting float input failed".to_string() }.fail()?
        }
    }
  }

impl CustomInput for MyIntInput{
    fn get_value(&self)->CustomOutputType{
      CustomOutputType::CInt(self.val)
    }
  fn set_value(&mut self, val: String)->Result<()>{
      match i32::from_str(&val) {
          Ok(inp)=>Ok(self.val = inp),
          Err(e) => IncorrectInputType { msg: "setting int input failed".to_string() }.fail()?
        }
      }
}

fn main() {
    let possible_inputs =  vec!["100".to_string(), "100.0".to_string(), "100/2".to_string(), ".1".to_string(), "teststr".to_string()];
    let mut int_input = MyIntInput{val: 0};
    let mut float_input = MyFloatInput{val: 0.0};
    for x in &possible_inputs{
      int_input.set_value(x.to_string()).unwrap();
      float_input.set_value(x.to_string()).unwrap();
    }
          
}
```

Comment: This is...needlessly complicated and inefficient. Evaluating inputs is already a difficult task, and trying to infer the input type on top of evaluating possible inputs (especially when considering that `100/2` is a valid path) is basically impossible. You should have separate functions for separate types and call different functions for different inputs based on what you think the type should be.

Comment: @Aplet123 So would that mean implementing such custom handling into ```set_value``` on a case by case basis for each UI Component? Do you have any example libraries or code that might exemplify the approach you are advocating?